# How to get string?

Tags: jquery, string

```
function checkInput3() {
    var fields = $('form').serializeArray();

    $('table tr').each(fields, function(index, value){
        alert(fields[value])
        $(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html(fields[value]);
    });
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to display the data, which serialize in an array in a table column

Comment: <script>
var fields = $('form').serializeArray();
$('table tr').each(function(index){
        $('td:nth-child(2)').text(fields[index]);
});
</script>

in response i receiving [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the jQuery `each` method correctly. It should be either:

```
// iterate through `tr` set
$('table tr').each(function(index, element) {
    // ...
});
```

Or using jQuery `$.each` utility function:

```
// iterate through `fields` array
$.each(fields, function(index, element) {
   // ...
});
```

Based on the posted code it seems you want to update textContent of each `td` using data returned by `serializeArray` method. `serializeArray` returns an array of objects. Each object has `name` and `value` property:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)').text(function(index, currentText) {
    return fields[index].value;
});
```

The above code assumes that `length` of the `fields` array and `length` of the `td` set are equal.